# how to check if stream is empty?

Tags: bash

For example I want to execute :

```
ps x | grep something | grep -v grep | somecommand
```

I want to execute `somecommand` only if there is something running. How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `if`. Also, to grep for a command, but to exclude the grep itself, you can use the following trick:

```
if ps x | grep '[s]omething' ; then
    echo Running.
else
    echo Not running.
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

This is simple:

```
pgrep something && somecommand
```

`pgrep` is like `ps | grep something | grep -v grep`, terser but with less options to control output. However, you don't have to worry that you filter out by chance something that actually is needed (e.g. `pgrep agreppina` will work, but `ps x | grep agreppina | grep -v grep` will not).

`command1 && command2` is somewhat like any conjunction in a programming language, command2 will be executed only if first command was successful (actually, if it returned a status of zero).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

`ps x | grep something | [[-n $(grep -v grep) ]] && somecommand`

- **-n** will check whether string is *null* or not
- **&&** is *and* operator